# Передача массива указателей на структуру в функцию

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, структуры

Битый час уже ломаю голову, поэтому очень прошу о помощи.
У нас есть указатели на уже готовые структуры и необходимо поместить их в массив указателей для дальнейшей сортировки.
(Основной код большой, поэтому показываю кривой костыль)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct elem {
    int key;
    int number;
};

void func(elem** arr, elem* q, int i) {
    arr[i] = q;
}


int main() {
    int n = 4;
    elem** arr = new elem*[n];
    elem q = { 2,0 }; elem w = { 5,1 }; elem e = { 10,4 }; elem r = { 54,5 };
    func(arr, &q, 0);
    func(arr, &w, 1);
    func(arr, &e, 2);
    func(arr, &r, 3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: В том, что это не работает( в функции в массив записывается только первый элемент(смею предположить, что arr расценивается как простой указатель)

Comment: Ваш код абсолютно рабочий https://ideone.com/brtqM7

Comment: Думаю, что у Вас проблема с чтением, а не записью

Comment: Ошибка где-то в другом месте, кажется.

Comment: А помещая в массив указатели на объекты с автоматическим временем жизни вы следите, что они не выходят из области видимости? И не помещаете ли вы случаем в цикле указатель на один и тот же объект?

Answer (score 1):

В функции main

```
elem* arr = new elem[n];
```

В функции задания элемента

```
void func(elem* arr, elem* q, int i) {
    arr[i] = *q;
}
```

Comment: Все еще не работает. Массив все так же продолжает состоять из одного элемента - {2,0}

Answer (score 1):

В этом коде все верно.

Добавьте

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  cout << arr[i]->key << ' ' << arr[i]->number << '\n';
```

и увидите:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out
2 0
5 1
10 4
54 5
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```